Как найти количество високосных годов между двумя датами?
Я пытаюсь найти формулу для поиска количества високосных годов между двумя датами (меньший год - всегда високосный). В формуле ошибка. Помогите найти верную.
Моя формула:

date=больший год - меньший год
кол-во високосных годов=date//4-date//100+date//400


В чем вопрос? Кстати в формуле ошибка. Результат не может зависеть только от разницы лет.

@stanislav Здравствуйте, ищу верную формулу или алгоритм. Лучше этой не придумал.

Ну алгоритм то не проблема - перебрать все года в промежутке и посчитать, какие из них високосные. Сколько тех годов то. Тыщу лет компьютер за наносекунды обсчитает. А вот с формулой сложнее, тут думать нужно.

@crazyelf В этом как раз и проблема, есть ограничение по времени, алгоритм не успевает.

@PlayGames Там миллионы лет что ли считают? Оптимисты ))

Вычитать годы нельзя. Потому что в паре 1896-1900 один високосный год, а в паре 1996-2000 два високосных года. А разница у обеих пар одна - четыре года.
Можно для каждого года из пары вычислить некоторое условное количество високосных лет с начала эпохи. Само по себе это число не имеет смысла, но разница таких чисел – количество високосных лет в промежутке. Если началом эпохи выбрать единицу (первый год нашей эры), формула будет проще всего:
fy = ⌊y/4⌋ - ⌊y/100⌋ + ⌊y/400⌋
Количество високосных лет на промежутке [y1, y2]:
Fy1,y2 = fy2 - fy1-1
def n_leap_years(y1, y2):

    def f(y):
        return y // 4 - y // 100 + y // 400

    return f(y2) - f(y1 - 1)


print(n_leap_years(*(map(int, input().split()))))

От первого до двухтысячного года было 485 високосных лет. Как я уже сказал это условное число, григорианский календарь так далеко в прошлое не простирается.

$ echo 1 2000 | python leap-years.py
485


А вот уже реальные примеры:

$ echo 1996 2000 | python leap-years.py
2

$ echo 1896 1900 | python leap-years.py
1



Существующая система дат, основана на григорианском календаре, впервые установленном в 1582 году папой римским Григорием XIII. Этот календарь был разработан для исправления ошибок, привнесенных менее точным юлианским календарем.

В григорианском календаре обычный год состоит из 365 дней. Поскольку фактическая продолжительность звездного года (период обращения Земли вокруг Солнца) составляет 365.2425 дней, «високосный год» в 366 дней используется один раз каждые четыре года для устранения ошибки, вызванной тремя обычными (но короткими) годами. Любой год, который делится на 4 без остатка, является високосным годом: например, 1988, 1992 и 1996 годы являются високосными годами.

Тем не менее, есть еще небольшая ошибка, которая должна быть учтена. Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, григорианский календарь предусматривает, что год, который делится без остатка на 100 (например, 1900) является високосным годом только в том случае, если он также без остатка делится на 400.

По этой причине следующие годы не являются високосными:

1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500, 2600

Это потому, что они делятся без остатка на 100, но не на 400.

Следующие годы – високосные: 1600, 2000, 2400

Это потому, что они делятся без остатка на 100 и 400.

Как определить, является ли год високосным
Чтобы определить, является ли год високосным, выполните следующие действия:


Если год делится на 4 без остатка, перейдите на шаг 2. В противном случае перейдите к выполнению действия 5.

Если год делится на 100 без остатка, перейдите на шаг 3. В противном случае перейдите к выполнению действия 4.

Если год делится на 400 без остатка, перейдите на шаг 4. В противном случае перейдите к выполнению действия 5.

Год високосный (366 дней).

Год не високосный год (365 дней).


Для сомневающихся это не GPT, это микрософт

Очевидно, что эта информация автору известна, а проблемы с ее правильным применением.

@MBo это ни разу не очевидно :-P

@Kromster А как же приведённая автором формула?

@MBo здесь часто постят фрагменты кода найденные в Интернете или ChatGPT со словами "вот я нашел и/или у меня есть и оно не работает, почему не знаю и знать не хочу, помогите, напишите за меня как надо". Особенно когда речь идёт об учебных заданиях. Так что нет, не очевидно :-)

Консольный скрипт:
import os

year_start = 2000
year_end = 2025

print(sum(1 for year in range(year_start, year_end) if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)))

os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


содержимое if'а можно засунуть в цикл вместо 1

Зачем вы везде это os.system("pause") добавляете? Есть много вариантов запуска, когда это не нужно. Лишнее это.

Я делаю готовую консольную утилиту. Я работаю ВСЕГДА под ключ. Поэтому ко мне и обращаются. И  не работаю в дебильных средах типа Pycharm. И я работаю именно с .py - именно поэтому у меня всё всегда работает, без сюрпризов, включая и автономные сборки. Я не рассчитываю на читателей, которые не в состоянии отделить служебный вспомогательный код от основного. Таким я не помогу всё равно.

Danis, я бы хотел увидеть рабочий код, а не разговоры. Речь идёт об одной строке, не так ли? Можно и в комменте.

Особенно нравится, как ставят -1. Это зависть? Это объективно? Код не работает? Он ошибочен, недопустим, неприемлем, неисполняем. Кто-то очень сильно переживает за рост чужого рейтинга? Это бывает. Между прочим, я тоже тратил время на решение.

Я делаю готовый продукт! Потому ко мне и обращаются. Текст надо взять в буфер и сохранить в файл! Там так и написано - КОНСОЛЬНЫЙ СКРИПТ!  Пишу я для  школьников, которым надо отправлять ФАЙЛ учителю, и для тех, кто В СОСТОЯНИИ ОТДЕЛИТЬ НЕБОЛЬШОЙ СЛУЖЕБНЫЙ КОД ОТ ИСПОЛНЯЕМОГО. И для тех, кто в состоянии взять нужный участок в буфер и вставить в тот свой глючный Pycharm.
А те, кто сидят в Windows XP, то есть в Линукс, сами знают, что брать, а что нет. Хорошо, я буду писать для особо страдающих: ЭТО ДЛЯ WINDOWS!  И да, рынок Windows - более 90%. Я работаю с большинством, и это правильно.

И я не пишу глючных программ. Если код не "подвесить", результат не увидят. Как я уже говорил, любители Windows XP (Линукс) разберутся. Хотя, я  скорее всего модернизирую команду подвешивания, я знаю как это делается.

Станислав, специально по Вашей просьбе и совету исправленный код в студию! Теперь буду только так!

Не надо писать не по серьёзной причине. А еще меньше мне интересны оценки типа "ваш код хуже или лучше". Это не язык программиста. Это ни о чём. И да, я пишу однострочниками. Меня беспокоит "высота скрипта". Моё поколение, из тех, кто ещё жив, читали программы на ассемблере, С. Эти питоновские сказочки  и близко по сложности закорючек не стоят с тем, что нам доводилось читать и писать. Я понимаю. Кто не понимает, пусть старается больше.

Stack Overflow — это база знаний, а не коллекция готовых консольных утилит «под ключ». В контексте базы знаний все эти принты и паузы замусоривают код, отвлекая от сути ответа

Не читайте слишком сложное. Ну а если вообще, вес для меня имеет то замечание, автор которого предлагает СВОЙ вариант, а не мои "инспектирует".
